# Array from js to php, error counting array length

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass an array from my .js file to a php file.
The array looks like the following in js:

```
theBlock[0 - 79] with the values color, x and y. So for example 
theBlock[10].color or
theBlock[79].x
```

This data is passed with the following script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert.php',
    data: $(theBlock).serialize()
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
    alert("Failed");
});
```

And the php is following:

```
$newData = $_POST;
echo count($newData["theBlock"]) . "\n";
```

Now when calling the function which activates this, the data should be passed to php which then sends me back the length of the array. Well, it always sends me back "0".

The array is created by the following script:

var theBlock = [];

```
for (c = 0; c < 80; c++) {
    theBlock.push({color: 0});
}
```

After that the array is changed in the following way:

```
if (ctx.getImageData(xPixel + minX, yPixel + minY, 1, 1).data[3] == 255 && ctx.getImageData(xPixel + minX, yPixel + minY, 1, 1).data[0] == 000) {
    id = (xBlock + (yBlock - 1) * 8) - 1;
    theBlock[id] = { color: 1, x: xBlock, y: yBlock };
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Print the values of $_POST to see what you actually get `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: When doing this I get: array(0) {}

Comment: Can we see the constructor for `theBlock` variable

Comment: I added the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't use serialize() on a javascript variable. Refer to the API documentation. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

If you want to encode a JSON array, use `JSON.stringify()` and then [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert.php',
    data: { block: JSON.stringify(theBlock) }
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
    alert("Failed");
});
```

And you don't need to assign $_POST to a variable, just use it directly.

```
echo count(json_decode($_POST['block'])) . "\n";
```

Sidenote: If you simply want to know the array length, you don't need PHP to do that. Just do `theBlock.length` and you get the length.

Comment: I need the data in the php, which is why I send it not because of the length but thx! Could you maybe tell me how I can access for example the first object in the array in php? I tried:
 `echo $newData[0]["color"];` but it gives me a internal server error. The $newData is already decoded. Thx!

Comment: If you didn't set keys, the default keys are numeric, so with 0 it should work. Print the array with `var_dump($newData);` to see how you need to access the values.

Comment: I tried that but I do not know how to read the var_dump stuff:
`array(80) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["color"]=>
    int(0)` How do I have to read this? btw this is not the whole output..

Comment: The first element of $newData is an object, so you have to handle it as an object. `$newData[0]->color`